# Ubuntu 16.04 route all traffic through OpenVPN using Network Manager

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, openvpn

On a clean ubuntu 18.04 server (amazon EC2), I installed openvpn access server 2.8.3 using the following commands taken from official documentation:

```
    1) apt update && apt -y install ca-certificates wget net-tools gnupg
    2) wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -
    3) echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian bionic main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
    4) apt update && apt -y install openvpn-as
```

Next, I went to the web face of the openvpn server https://xxx:943 and downloaded the client.ovpn configuration file.

The contents of client.ovpn:

```
    client
    cipher AES-256-CBC
    setenv FORWARD_COMPATIBLE 1
    server-poll-timeout 4
    nobind
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 443 tcp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    dev tun
    dev-type tun
    ns-cert-type server
    setenv opt tls-version-min 1.0 or-highest
    #reneg-sec 604800
    sndbuf 0
    rcvbuf 0
    auth-user-pass
    comp-lzo no
    verb 3
    setenv PUSH_PEER_INFO
```

I work on an ubuntu 16.04 desktop where I installed network-manager-openvpn-gnome.
I did import client.ovpn. After which I try to connect to openvpn in the network manager.[image]

The connection is successful, the internal VPN network is working, but my internet stopped working. Internet traffic does not want to work through a VPN. I need my entire Internet traffic to start working through a vpn server.
In the server settings there is a option that the client’s Internet traffic should be routed through a VPN, but for some reason this does not happen.[image]

Please tell me what could be the problem?
If you connect via terminal (sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn), then all Internet traffic is routed through the openvpn server, as I need.
If I connect through OpenVPN Client Connect For Windows 7, also no problems. But I need to configure this in network-manager.